# How to delete all channels In a discord server(js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am attempting to delete channels on my discord server using my bot and this is the code:

```js
if (message.content === 'tanbu')
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

the error is :

`TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function`

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would've worked in Discord JS V11, but not in V12.

This is what you're looking for:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete());
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think twice before doing such actions. Because this leads to violation of the Discord tos. And it even spams the discord api. which could lead you to a api ban to a particular endpoint or globally sometimes. Even if the library has ability to slow down it , you could still easily bypass it. The ideal solution here is using a sleep function , and not using a `forEach` loop, maybe a for loop would do better.
Still this is not recommended doing , if your intention is to nuke servers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that is for raiding and self bots witch is against discord **TOS**
i defiently would think w

Comment: It looks like this got posted before you finished your thought? Or was that last "w" meant to be period? Regardless, I'd edit your answer to check spelling and make sure it's clear. It may also be useful to link to their terms of service to support the concern.

Comment: i came here to make a bot to clear a test server.